# Help cleaning snaps in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, snap

Hi these days im cleaning my ubuntu 22.04 system, that has been upgraded from 20.04, which was upgraded from 18.04 which cames from 16.04 … Just to clean as much as i can, and to learn new things.

My problem is that i face this snap list:

```
    eduardo@MiPcLinux:/opt/AppImages$ snap list --all
Nombre                     Versión                     Rev    Seguimiento      Editor               Notas
atom                       1.60.0                      286    latest/stable    snapcrafters         classic
atom                       1.57.0                      282    latest/stable    snapcrafters         desactivado,classic
bare                       1.0                         5      latest/stable    canonical✓           base
canonical-livepatch        10.1.5                      138    latest/stable    canonical✓           desactivado
canonical-livepatch        10.2.3                      146    latest/stable    canonical✓           -
chromium                   105.0.5195.52               2076   latest/stable    canonical✓           -
chromium                   104.0.5112.101              2064   latest/stable    canonical✓           desactivado
communitheme               0.1                         1768   latest/stable    didrocks             desactivado
communitheme               29.187                      1987   latest/stable    didrocks             -
core                       16-2.56                     13308  latest/stable    canonical✓           core,desactivado
core                       16-2.56.2                   13425  latest/stable    canonical✓           core
core18                     20220428                    2409   latest/stable    canonical✓           base,desactivado
core18                     20220706                    2538   latest/stable    canonical✓           base
core20                     20220805                    1611   latest/stable    canonical✓           base
core20                     20220729                    1593   latest/stable    canonical✓           base,desactivado
cups                       2.4.2-2                     766    latest/stable    openprinting✓        desactivado
cups                       2.4.2-2                     774    latest/stable    openprinting✓        -
dbeaver-ce                 22.1.4.202208051447         204    latest/stable    dbeaver-corp         desactivado
dbeaver-ce                 22.1.5.202208211008         205    latest/stable    dbeaver-corp         -
discord                    0.0.19                      138    latest/stable    snapcrafters         desactivado
discord                    0.0.19                      141    latest/stable    snapcrafters         -
eclipse                    2019-03                     40     latest/stable    snapcrafters         desactivado,classic
eclipse                    2019-12                     48     latest/stable    snapcrafters         classic
exelearning                2.6                         9      latest/stable    exelearning-project  desactivado
exelearning                2.7                         10     latest/stable    exelearning-project  -
firefox                    104.0.1-1                   1794   latest/stable    mozilla✓             -
firefox                    104.0.1-1                   1775   latest/stable    mozilla✓             desactivado
gnome-3-26-1604            3.26.0.20210629             104    latest/stable    canonical✓           -
gnome-3-26-1604            3.26.0.20210401             102    latest/stable    canonical✓           desactivado
gnome-3-28-1804            3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable    canonical✓           -
gnome-3-28-1804            3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓           desactivado
gnome-3-38-2004            0+git.891e5bc               115    latest/stable    canonical✓           -
gnome-3-38-2004            0+git.891e5bc               112    latest/stable    canonical✓           desactivado
gtk-common-themes          0.1-79-ga83e90c             1534   latest/stable    canonical✓           desactivado
gtk-common-themes          0.1-81-g442e511             1535   latest/stable    canonical✓           -
gtk2-common-themes         0.1                         13     latest/stable    canonical✓           -
intellij-idea-ultimate     2022.2.1                    380    latest/stable    jetbrains✓           classic
intellij-idea-ultimate     2022.2                      377    latest/stable    jetbrains✓           desactivado,classic
jdownloader2               0+git.c17098b               17     latest/stable    fnkr                 -
jdownloader2               0+git.295de45               16     latest/stable    fnkr                 desactivado
onlyoffice-desktopeditors  7.1.0                       115    latest/stable    onlyoffice✓          desactivado
onlyoffice-desktopeditors  7.1.1                       121    latest/stable    onlyoffice✓          -
onlyoffice-ds              7.1.1                       88     latest/edge      onlyoffice✓          desactivado
onlyoffice-ds              7.1.1                       90     latest/edge      onlyoffice✓          -
p7zip-desktop              16.02.2                     220    latest/stable    ernytech             -
phpstorm                   2022.2                      286    latest/stable    jetbrains✓           desactivado,classic
phpstorm                   2022.2.1                    289    latest/stable    jetbrains✓           classic
pycharm-professional       2022.2                      297    latest/stable    jetbrains✓           desactivado,classic
pycharm-professional       2022.2.1                    300    latest/stable    jetbrains✓           classic
snap-store                 3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7          558    latest/stable    canonical✓           -
snapd-desktop-integration  0.1                         14     latest/stable/…  canonical✓           -
spark                      1.2.0                       24     latest/edge      kwmonroe             -
spotify                    1.1.80.699.gc3dac750        58     latest/stable    spotify✓             desactivado
spotify                    1.1.84.716.gc5f8b819        60     latest/stable    spotify✓             -
webstorm                   2022.2.1                    276    latest/stable    jetbrains✓           classic
webstorm                   2022.2                      274    latest/stable    jetbrains✓           desactivado,classic
```

So i have some problems:

1 - For example as far as i know ubuntu 22.04.1 comes with gnome 42 and some apps still in gnome 41, So i can safely remove gnome-3-26-1604 and gnome-3-28-1804 and gnome gnome-3-38-2004 snaps ? Also i could delete their repective versions ?

2 - What about core ? I have core,core18,core20 … I suppose this is the core of snap, so i should save at least one core ? The latest one ?

3 - Snapd-desktop-integration is necessary…its name suggests that yes is important, but the version 0.1 suggests that is abandonware or something no used anymore…perhaps integrated in other place

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend leaving the core snaps installed. These are the base dependencies for other snaps. If a snap should need a specific core snap, it will be installed, but it's just as easy to let all core snaps be on your system, since they don't take up much space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try removing `gnome-` and `core-` snaps that you believe to be unused. If you are wrong, the system will merely return an error telling you exactly which snaps are using it.

Here are two examples of attempted removal of `core-`:

```
me@me:~$ sudo snap remove core18
core18 removed

me@me:~$ sudo snap remove core20
error: cannot remove "core20": snap "core20" is not removable: snap is being used by snaps discord,
       firefox, gnome-3-38-2004, snap-store, snapd-desktop-integration and 1 more.
```

Do not remove `snapd-desktop-integration`

- See https://github.com/snapcore/snapd-desktop-integration for details on what this snap is and what it does.
- Version 0.1 means that is in an early stage of development, not that it is abandoned.